# Python 2 error:"Internal Python error in the inspect module

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have written this code to calculate the quadratic formula:

```
from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt as csqrt

a = raw_input("a?")

b = raw_input("b?")

c = raw_input("c?")

def numcheck(x):
    try:
       i = float(x)
       return True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
       return False

if numcheck(a)==True:
    a=int(a)
else:
    print "a is not a number"

if numcheck(b)==True:
    b=int(b)
else:
    print "b is not a number"

if numcheck(c)==True:
    c=int(c)
else:
    print "b is not a number"


sqrt= ((b*b) - (4* (a*c)))

x_minus= (-b+(csqrt(sqrt)))/(2*a)
x_minus=str(x_minus)

x_plus= (-b-(csqrt(sqrt)))/(2*a)
x_plus=str(x_plus)

print "The solution is "+x_plus+" or "+x_minus
```

Never minding the rather crappy style, when the input is not a number, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 776, in structured_traceback
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 230, in wrapped
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 267, in _fixed_getinnerframes
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and, if possible, a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an IPython bug.

Comment: Any chance you could use Python 3 instead?

Answer (score 0):

To do a sqrt, you can simply do this:

```
def sqrt(num):
    return num ** 0.5
```

I'll try to give you more info related to your problem, but for now try to replace your sqrt with that one.